# webGL skybox rendering issues - even gl.clearColor isn't working

Tags: typescript, webgl

This is my HTML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebGL Demo Project : Group 9</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100vw;height:90vh;display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
    <div style="width:70vw;height:90vh;display:flex;flex-direction:row;margin:10px;">
        <canvas id="canvas" style="height:100%;width:100%;margin:2px;border:1px solid black;"/>
    </div>
    <div style="width:30vw;height:100vw;display:flex;flex-direction:column;" >
        <div style="margin-bottom:8px;"> Camera Position </div>
        <div style="width: 100vw; display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
        <div>Camera X Position </div>
        <div>
            <input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="xPosition"/>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:5px;"> X axis Log? </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="logX" name="Log X Scale"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100vw; display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
        <div>Camera Y Position </div>
        <div>
            <input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="yPosition"/>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:5px;"> Y axis Log? </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="logY" name="Log Y Scale"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100vw; display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
        <div>Camera Z Position </div>
        <div>
            <input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="zPosition"/>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:5px;"> Z axis Log? </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="logZ" name="Log Z Scale"/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:8px;">Select Renderer [Auto Update] </div>
        <div style="width: 100vw; display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
        <div>RayTracer </div>
        <input type="radio" id="rend0" name="rend" value="30"/>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100vw; display:flex; flex-direction:row;">
        <div>Rasterizer </div>
        <input type="radio" id="rend1" name="rend" value="30"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>                              <!-- This file holds the baseline commands -->
    <script type="module" src="globals.js"></script>                            <!-- This file holds the baseline commands -->
    <script type="module" src="generic/input_controls.js"></script>             <!-- This file manages the inputs from sliders, color pickers, etc -->
    <script type="module" src="graphics/drawItems.js"></script>

    <script>
        // document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        //  // Call the drawScene function when the DOM is fully loaded
        //  drawScene();
        // });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my drawItems.ts file. I am trying to draw a skybox

```
/*
* This file contains all the information
* needed to draw the basics.
*/

// ------------------------- load assets ----------------------------------- //

//import cubeObj from '../build/assets/objects/cube.obj';                                                       // a 3d CUBE object with vertices and nodes, and faces defined
                                            // note that the camera is "inside" the cube

let MatType = Float32Array;

// ------------------------- Some  basics ---------------------------------- //

const eps = 0.00000001;
const array4x4 = (typeof Float32Array !== 'undefined') ? Float32Array : Array;




// -------------------- Drawing the Canvas Pane itself --------------------- //
/*
* Step 1 : Draw the background of the GL Canvas (SkyBox)
* * Ensure, that both renderes can work with it
* Step 2 : Draw the Launch Icons
* * The requirement does not require that the launch icons need to be mobile [OPTIONAL]
* * There will be two application icons
* * There will be one Task Bar.
* * * * Set Task bar to the bottom (Not movable)
* * * * Set height = 32 px constant
* * * * Set texture Constant
* These are immobile 2D objects
*
*/

function drawSkyBox() {                                                                                     console.log("DrawItems called");

    /*
     * This function will be called when the canvas in the HTML file finishes loading
     * It can be the case, that the canvas is loaded before the TS (compiled to JS) file is loaded.
     * Therefore, it will be called again at the end of the function definition
     * Whichever happens at the correct time, will draw the Skybox
     *
     * INPUTS : NONE
     * OUTPUTS : ALSO NONE
     * JOB : Renders the textures of a cube that will be the skybox
     *
     */

    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');



    const vShaderSource = `

        attribute vec4 a_position;                                                                          // Typscript will grasp here,a nd set the values
        varying vec4 v_position;
        void main() {
            v_position = a_position;
            gl_Position = a_position;
            gl_Position.z = 1.0;
        }
    `;                                                                                                      // we write the shader source directly in the code for simplicity


    const fShaderSource = `

        precision mediump float;                                                                            // here, we need to set the precision

        uniform samplerCube u_skybox;                                                                       // typescript will grasp here
        uniform mat4 u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse;

        varying vec4 v_position;
        void main() {
            vec4 t = u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse * v_position;
            gl_FragColor = textureCube(u_skybox, normalize(t.xyz / t.w));
        }
    `                                                                                                       // also the vertexshader is directly added here

    const vShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);                                                      // shader program placeholders created. vShader is vertex shader
    const fShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);                                                    // shader program placeholders created. fShader is fragment shader

    gl.shaderSource(vShader, vShaderSource);
    gl.compileShader(vShader);

    gl.shaderSource(fShader, fShaderSource);                                                                // the strings which are the source code of the shaders
    gl.compileShader(fShader)                                                                               // are inserted in the placeholders; and then compiled

    const program = gl.createProgram();                                                                     // now, create a shader *program*, which can run the compiled shaders
    gl.attachShader(program, vShader);                                                                      // compilation result attached to program
    gl.attachShader(program, fShader);                                                                      // ..

    gl.linkProgram(program);

    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");                                     // as marked above , the typescript will grab on "a_positions"
                                                                                                            // the vertex data will go there
    var skyboxLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_skybox");                                        // same here in the fragmentshader
    var viewDirectionProjectionInverseLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse");

    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    var positions = new Float32Array(
        [
        -1, -1,
        1, -1,
        -1,  1,
        -1,  1,
        1, -1,
        1,  1,
        ]
    );
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);

    const faceInfos = [
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,
        url: './../build/assets/images/skybox/front.JPG',
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
        url: './../build/assets/images/skybox/back.JPG',
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,
        url: './../build/assets/images/skybox/left.JPG',
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
        url: './../build/assets/images/skybox/right.JPG',
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z,
        url: './../build/assets/images/skybox/up.JPG',
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z,
        url: './../build/assets/images/skybox/down.JPG',
        },
    ];

    //document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundImage= "url('./../build/assets/images/skybox/down.JPG')";

    faceInfos.forEach((faceInfo) => {
        const {target, url} = faceInfo;

        // Upload the canvas to the cubemap face.
        const level = 0;
        const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
        const width = 512;
        const height = 512;
        const format = gl.RGBA;
        const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;

        // setup each face so it's immediately renderable
        gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, type, null);

        // Asynchronously load an image
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = url;
        image.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Now that the image has loaded make copy it to the texture.
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
            gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, format, type, image);
            gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
        });
    });

    console.log(gl);

    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.clearColor(1, 0.5, 0.5, 3);
    gl.useProgram(program);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);


    var size = 2;                                                                                           // 2 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;                                                                                    // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false;                                                                                  // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;                                                                                         // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;                                                                                         // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);



    var aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;

    var viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1];
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( viewDirectionProjectionInverseLocation, false, viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix);

    gl.uniform1i(skyboxLocation, 0);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 1 * 6);
                                                                                                            console.log("Skybox drawn");


}

drawSkyBox();
```

This compiles, and the `console.log()`, both at the beginning and the end of the function fire. The assets are in correct place --> if I dynamically load them as a background image, then they can be seen.

**Problem**

The skybox isn't rendered.

**Attempt to solution**

I took the code mostly from [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-skybox.html) with slight modifications. But there is absolutely nothing visible.

Even the gl.clearcolor (which is set to be a salmon color) has no effect.

I tested whether the assets are loading, they are.

Ofcourse the inverse Matrix in my code is not the correct one - that is just a test. But if I apply the same inverse matrix to the original code linked above, I see a distorted skybox. In my code as included in this question, has nothing at all in it's canvas.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a first step create an executable mvce and set the clear color before you call `clear`. Also ensure that the dimensions of the images you upload into the cube map are indeed a power of two (like 512x512).